# How to iterate some characters in a string and other character stay on the same position in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, permutation, synonym

I have a text say for example,

`t = "The climate is super awesome"`

by doing,

`from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
words = word_tokenize(t)`

what I got,

`>>>words = ["The","climate","is","super","awesome"]`

and I have multiple lists in a dictionary each having a list of synonyms.
for example,

`dict = {'climate' : [weather,region,zone], 'super' : [excellent, superior, outstanding], 'awesome' : [amazing,great,stunning]}`

How to write the code to get the permutation combinations of the synonyms in the sentence.
Assume that we have at least or exactly 3 identified synonyms for each of our words.
Then totally there are 3 words in the selected first line of 't'.
Therefore 3 to the power of 3 sentences = 27 sentences are possible to generate.

and how the output I want ?

```
The weather is excellent amazing
The weather is excellent great
The weather is excellent stunning
The weather is superior amazing
The weather is superior great
The weather is superior stunning
The weather is outstanding amazing
The weather is outstanding great
The weather is outstanding stunning
The region is excellent amazing
The region is excellent great
The region is excellent stunning
The region is superior amazing
The region is superior great
The region is superior stunning
The region is outstanding amazing
The region is outstanding great
The region is outstanding stunning
The zone is excellent amazing
The zone is excellent great
The zone is excellent stunning
The zone is superior amazing
The zone is superior great
The zone is superior stunning
The zone is outstanding amazing
The zone is outstanding great
The zone is outstanding stunning
```

Any help regarding this, will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `itertools.product` and `str.replace`:

```
words = ["The","climate","is","super","awesome"]
synonyms = {'climate' : ['weather','region','zone'],
            'super' : ['excellent', 'superior', 'outstanding'],
            'awesome' : ['amazing','great','stunning']}

from itertools import product

s = ' '.join(words)

for val in product(*[[(k, i) for i in v] for k, v in synonyms.items()]):
    new_s = s
    for (orig, new_one) in val:
        new_s = new_s.replace(orig, new_one)
    print(new_s)
```

Prints:

```
The weather is excellent amazing
The weather is excellent great
The weather is excellent stunning
The weather is superior amazing
The weather is superior great
The weather is superior stunning
The weather is outstanding amazing
The weather is outstanding great
The weather is outstanding stunning
The region is excellent amazing
The region is excellent great
The region is excellent stunning
The region is superior amazing
The region is superior great
The region is superior stunning
The region is outstanding amazing
The region is outstanding great
The region is outstanding stunning
The zone is excellent amazing
The zone is excellent great
The zone is excellent stunning
The zone is superior amazing
The zone is superior great
The zone is superior stunning
The zone is outstanding amazing
The zone is outstanding great
The zone is outstanding stunning
```

Answer (score 1):

If your input dictionary is always in the form as describe above, you could simply do:

```
for x in d["climate"]:
    for y in d["super"]:
        for z in d["awesome"]:
            print("The {} is {} {}".format(x, y, z))
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it seems to work:

```py
import re
words = ["The","climate","is","super","awesome"]
synons = {'climate' : ['weather','region','zone'], 'super' : ['excellent', 'superior', 'outstanding'], 'awesome' : ['amazing','great','stunning']}

phrases = {' '.join(words)}
for word, synonyms in synons.items():
    for syn in synonyms:
        for p in list(phrases):
            phrases.add(re.sub(r"\b%s\b" % word, syn, p))

print('\n'.join(sorted(phrases)))
```

Output:

```py
The climate is excellent amazing
The climate is excellent awesome
The climate is excellent great
The climate is excellent stunning
The climate is outstanding amazing
The climate is outstanding awesome
The climate is outstanding great
The climate is outstanding stunning
The climate is super amazing
The climate is super awesome
The climate is super great
The climate is super stunning
The climate is superior amazing
The climate is superior awesome
The climate is superior great
The climate is superior stunning
The region is excellent amazing
The region is excellent awesome
The region is excellent great
The region is excellent stunning
The region is outstanding amazing
The region is outstanding awesome
The region is outstanding great
The region is outstanding stunning
The region is super amazing
The region is super awesome
The region is super great
The region is super stunning
The region is superior amazing
The region is superior awesome
The region is superior great
The region is superior stunning
The weather is excellent amazing
The weather is excellent awesome
The weather is excellent great
The weather is excellent stunning
The weather is outstanding amazing
The weather is outstanding awesome
The weather is outstanding great
The weather is outstanding stunning
The weather is super amazing
The weather is super awesome
The weather is super great
The weather is super stunning
The weather is superior amazing
The weather is superior awesome
The weather is superior great
The weather is superior stunning
The zone is excellent amazing
The zone is excellent awesome
The zone is excellent great
The zone is excellent stunning
The zone is outstanding amazing
The zone is outstanding awesome
The zone is outstanding great
The zone is outstanding stunning
The zone is super amazing
The zone is super awesome
The zone is super great
The zone is super stunning
The zone is superior amazing
The zone is superior awesome
The zone is superior great
The zone is superior stunning
```

Comment: I notice now that your output did not include the original phrase in the bag of synonyms, but maybe it will be useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `dict` is (more appropriately) named `synonyms`, and you clean up its syntax errors, this should do the job:

```
import itertools
for x in itertools.product(*[synonyms.get(x,[x]) for x in words]):
    print(" ".join(x))
```